# Adding date to pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm looking for a way to add custom date to pd.to_datetime. So, for example:

```
csv_file = str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + '.csv'
csv_file2 = str((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) + '.csv'
data = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, [csv_file, csv_file2]))
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], errors='coerce')
```

Print:

```
4      2021-08-23 00:00:40
20     2021-08-23 00:02:54
36     2021-08-23 00:05:09
...
```

pd.to_datetime keeps adding today's date which is fine in case of *csv_file* but *csv_file2* need to contain tomorrow's date.

Here's sample of csv files:

```
piece,time
2259,12:03:50
2259,12:07:42
2259,12:34:05
2259,12:45:29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is create helper column `file` for distingush if `tomorrow` and last add `1 day` by condition for compare `new` column:

```
data = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, [csv_file, csv_file2]), keys=('today','tomorrow'))

data = data.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename_axis('new').reset_index()

d = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], errors='coerce')
data['time'] = np.where(data['new'].eq('tomorrow'), d + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'), d)
```

Or:

```
files = [csv_file, csv_file2]
names = ('today','tomorrow')
data= pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(new=name) for f, name in zip(files, names)])
d = pd.to_datetime(data['time'], errors='coerce')
data['time'] = np.where(data['new'].eq('tomorrow'), d + pd.Timedelta(1, 'd'), d)
```